# What does the C++ standard guarantee regarding the storage, allocation of local variables?

Tags: c++, memory, standards

Let's consider this simple C++ code:

```
struct vector3d { double x, y, z; };

void foo()
{
    vector3d v;
    ...
}
```

What does C++ say about the location of `v`? My guess would be: nothing, and that would make sense as C++ should not bother with such underlying memory concepts.

But if the C++ standard does not talk about the specific concepts of stack, heap and thus dynamic memory allocation, how does it guarantee in such case that the compiler would not choose to translate this line with an underlying call to `malloc` instead of a classic `sub rsp, X`?

In the case it does not guarantee anything, does C guarantee something (out of curiosity)? Is it just widely assumed by all C++ developers that this will be on the stack?

Thanks!

Comment: Variables in C++ are stored on the stack... if you wanna stay on heap you can use `new` operator or `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr`... but in the end them use `new`

Comment: *"how does it guarantee in such case that the compiler would not choose to translate this line with an underlying call to malloc instead of a classic sub rsp, X"* - It doesn't. Which is precisely why we may see co-routines come in C++20.

Comment: @elvis.dukaj "_Variables in C++ are stored on the stack_" As question stated - C++ standard doesn't even mention `stack`, or `heap`. So, nothing is forbidding one to write a compiler which doesn't store variables on stack, and, still, be standard-compliant.

Comment: Look up "automatic variable" and "free store" in the standard.

Comment: Have a read of Object (Standard definition of):  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/object and Lifetime: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lifetime

Comment: Such a compiler would not get much of a user base.

Comment: If `foo()` is never called recursively (or multi-threaded), the local variable could be allocated at a fixed address.

Comment: @elvis.dukaj:  Compilers are allowed to store variables in *registers*.  Tell your compiler to generate an assembly language listing and look at the use of registers.  Some variables may not have a memory location, but are temporarily stored in *registers*.  Compilers can optimize and store data members in separate registers.

Comment: @StoryTeller Interesting, could you elaborate? Why co-routines are related to the fact that memory storage is leaving undefined by the standard?

Comment: @AntiClimacus - The state of a coroutine (the values of all local variables in its scope) must be preserved when it yields control to the calling code. The calling code may call a regular function after it, and that doesn't play well with a stack once we scale up. So the easier implementation is to allocate the state on the free store or heap. Since the standard doesn't force a "call stack" it doesn't need to adapt its scoping rules to support coroutines (though it still needs to adapt elsewhere of course).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're correct that the C++ standard does not directly say anything about this. Indeed, concepts such as "stack" or "heap" do not make sense from the standard's POV.

This is effectively a Quality Of Implementation issue, and other than the hypothetical Hell++ (whose motto would be to "stick to RAW and violate RAI as much as possible"), no compiler has a reason to store automatic-duration local variables on the heap.

Comment: The standard mentions the term "stack" when describing exception handling and details the concept in describing how objects are destructed in the reverse order of their construction - *stack unwinding*.

Comment: *"creating a function-scope automatic variable has no legal way to fail"* Does it mean that crashing due to stack overflow is not conforming?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Oops, seems I worded it a bit too strongly. I'll think of a better way to express what I meant.

Comment: Where can I get my hands on Hell++?

Comment: @PasserBy It's unfortunately still hypothetical. Sometimes, it could be quite useful, though.

Comment: @Angew Thanks for your answer! What does `RAI` mean here?

Comment: @AntiClimacus RAW - **R**ules **A**s **W**ritten. RAI - **R**ules **A**s **I**ntended.

Comment: Hell++ is a C++ implementation for a DeathStation 9000 machine, I guess?  Anyway, @Anti: see also [How was C ported to architectures that had no hardware stack?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/7197).  Supercat's answer shows just how much it sucks to fully implement ISO C, which supports arbitrary recursion.  But that real compilers had an option to not support recursion at all, and use static storage for locals.  Semi-related, (retrocomputing.SE: [Why do C to Z80 compilers produce poor code?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/6095)) (has a stack but not easy indexing)

Answer (score 3):

The fact is that local objects (automatic objects) MUST be destroyed in reverse order from their creation. So the **concept** of a stack is inherent in how the Standard expects local variables to behave. It also mentions the term "stack unwinding" when describing object destruction.

The term "stack" as a *general computing term* is thus well applied to `C++` local variables. How such a "stack" is implemented and where in memory it might be located are up for grabs but a stack is basically a *concept* that being Last In First Out. That is how the C++ Standard says local object creation/destruction must occur.

The term "heap", though not used in the standard, is a *general computing term* that applies exactly to what the C++ Standard's "free store" does. It is a general area where arbitrary chunks of storage may be obtained and returned.

So the Standard does dictate that C++ programs need (at least) these two types of storage. One that behaves like a stack (destroy in reverse order of creation) and one that behaves like a heap (arbitrary allocation/deallocation).

Comment: The standard also allows for local variables to be stored in processor registers.  Local variables are not always placed in the stack.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews My point is that "the stack" is a concept which dictates the order of creation and destruction of objects. It doesn't matter *where* you actually store them, it is still a stack when the last created is the first to be destroyed. That *concept* is embodied in the standard. So implementation details are irrelevant.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews The standard still uses the term "stack unwinding" during an exception even though *some* of the objects on the *unwinding stack* may only exist in CPU registers.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews In fact the Standard doesn't mention CPU registers at all. They are permissible because the compiler only needs to behave **as if** the standard is being adhered to. So the Standard describes *stack like* behavior but the compiler is allowed to implement that how it likes **as long as** it behaves like a stack.